# A call to PInvoke function 'ABC' has unbalanced the stack.

Tags: pinvoke, unmanaged

I have a C# application (x86 .net 3.5 on Windows 7 vs2010) which call a C function

when I upgrade it to .net 4, I got the following message:

This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

C signature:

BOOL ABC( UDF_HANDLE handle, char* pQualifiedName )
//#define UDF_HANDLE      void*

C# side:

```
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    [DllImport(dllPath, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    internal static extern int ABC(
        [In] IntPtr handle,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string qualifiedName);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: here it is signature in the header file:   int ABC( int handle, char* pQualifiedName );

Comment: The problem is here in the definition:  BOOL ABC( UDF_HANDLE handle, char* pQualifiedName ) //#define UDF_HANDLE void*  and the definition in the header file :         int ABC( int handle, char* pQualifiedName );

Answer (score 0):

I redefined ABC first parameter to be same as the first parameter in the function.

Comment: On x86, int and IntPtr are the same size so your answer explains nothing

Answer (score 0):

The C++ code uses the cdecl calling convention. But you've specified stdcall in your p/invoke. Change that in the C# code and your two declarations will match.